# Using replace in SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I want to remove any break tags from one of my database fields and replace it with a space.
so I tried the following:

```
$select = SELECT ID, REPLACE(fieldname, "<BR>", " ") FROM mytable
```

but this results in an unexpected > error. I also tried `'<BR>'` but this just made the field name in the csv change to `REPLACE(fieldname, '<BR>', ' ')`

Anyone who could point me in the right direction?

Comment: -1 for not posting (and even not reading either) **full error text** which obviously contains the vital information explaining the problem cause. Or at least helps to determine, which part - PHP or Mysql it belongs

Answer (score 2):

How about mysql_query()?

```
$select = mysql_query('SELECT ID, REPLACE(fieldname, "<BR>", " ") FROM mytable');
```

**UPDATE**

I tried it from phpMyAdmin

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`fieldname` TEXT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

INSERT INTO `usr_web106_38`.`mytable` (`fieldname`)VALUES ('test <BR> test <BR>');
```

And the query works:

```
SELECT ID, REPLACE( fieldname, "<BR>", " " ) FROM mytable;

ID  REPLACE(fieldname, "<BR>", " ")
1   test   test
```

So did the PHP

```
$select = mysql_query('SELECT ID, REPLACE(fieldname, "<BR>", " ") FROM mytable');
echo "<pre>"; var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($select) ); echo "</pre>";
```

Result

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "test   test  "
  ["REPLACE(fieldname, "
", " ")"]=>
  string(13) "test   test  "
}
```

What ever your problem might be. It is not visible to us.

Comment: I'd prefer: `mysql_query("SELECT ID, REPLACE(fieldname, '<BR>', ' ') FROM mytable")`

Comment: I would, too. I was just a bit lasy here ;)

Comment: that gives me the error: Sql error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #2' at line 1

Comment: Please post more code and make sure table and fieldname exist in the database.

Comment: id and fieldname both exist as does the table - there isnt really anything else code wise to show :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$select = SELECT ID, REPLACE(fieldname, "<BR>", " ") FROM mytable

//1 : Syntax Error no quotes & semicolon

$select =  'SELECT ID, REPLACE(fieldname, "<BR>", " ") FROM mytable';

//2 : you've to run query 

mysql_query($select);
?>
```

Comment: that is actually what i had i missed the quotes and semicolon out when i retyped here sorry. This however does not remove the br tags hence the question.